# why kafka index files use memory mapped files ,but log files don't?

Tags: apache-kafka

We know that kafka use memory mapped files for it's index files ,however it's log files don't use the memory mapped files technology.

My question is why index files use memory mapped files, however log files don't ?

Answer (score 3):

Implementing both log and index appending with mmap approach will bring data consistency problem. mmap is not 100% guarantee to flush the data from memory to file(assuming the flush reply on OS instead of an explicitly calling on munmap(2)), if the index update get flushed but log data not get flushed successfully due to some reason, the data in the log can not be understood anymore.

BTW, for a append-only data, in the write direction, we only need to care about next-to-write block(buffer), so the huge data should not impact this.

Answer (score 2):

That how many bytes can be mapped into the memory relates to the address space. For example, a 32-bit architecture can only address 4GB or even smaller portions of files. Kafka logs which are often larger enough might have only portions mapped at a time, therefore complicating reading them.

However, index files are sparse which means they are relatively small in size. Mapping them into the memory could speed up the lookup process and that's the primary benefit memory-mapped files offer.

Comment: From your answer it seems that Kafka logs are large, so it not fit for using  Memory-mapped files, however based on my understanding, the Memory-mapped files is more suitable to deal with large file, as it can just map part of the large file to memory instead of the whole large file.

Comment: I am not saying it's not suitable for large files, but loading portions of it will complicate the reading.

Comment: It seems don't make sense KAFKA gives up the performance improvement by using memory-mapped files just in order to simplify the reading.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are where the messages are stored, the index files point to the position in the logs.

There is a nice, colorful [blog post, explaining what is going on](https://thehoard.blog/how-kafkas-storage-internals-work-3a29b02e026).

Comment: In fact ,I know "Logs are where the messages are stored, the index files point to the position in the logs." , however my question is why index files use memory mapped files ,but log files don't use that technology?

Answer (score 0):

Having a fast index to improve read performance is a common optimization in databases where writes are append-only(Almost all LSTM databases do some form of this). Also as others have pointed out:

- indexes are sparse, so smaller memory footprint. Even the sparsity of the index is configurable, which is useful as data grows.
- Append only write patterns are faster than random seeks(especially true for SSDs), and therefore don't need a lot of attention for optimization.

Answer (score 0):

if mmap log file, as physical memory is limited, it may cause page fault frequently which is a seriously expensive overhead. use sendFile system call is more suitable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).